# Renderizar meu react em outros projetos

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, react, render

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de exportar meu projeto react e importar em outros projetos com um link, a ideia seria hospedar meu projeto e poder acessar meus componentes através de um link parecido com este abaixo:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/yourcode.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Sim, mas provavelmente vai ter que fazer algo semelhante ao que o react-scripts faz na mão, pode dar uma olhada em como as bibliotecas que exportam componentes React fazem. Já fiz isso e usei [esse tutorial](https://dev.to/alexeagleson/how-to-create-and-publish-a-react-component-library-2oe), que usa o Rollup, funciona muito bem